# How do I properly update entity relationships in Typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, lazy-loading, typeorm

I have a basic User table in which they can have proficiencies in various musical Instruments. I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to make a basic `updateUser` function in which they can update their User information, as well as their instrument proficiencies using Typeorm and a MySQL database.

#### User Class

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  public constructor(init?:Partial<User>) {
      super();
      Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  @Index({ unique: true})
  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Index({ unique: true})
  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  @HideField()
  password: string;

  @Column({
      nullable: true
  })
  profilePicture?: string;

  @Index({ unique: true})
  @Column()
  phoneNumber: string;

  //Lazy loading
  @OneToMany(() => UserInstrument, p => p.user, {
      cascade: true
  })
  instruments?: Promise<UserInstrument[]>;
}
```

#### User Instrument Class

```
@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class UserInstrument extends BaseEntity {

  public constructor(init?:Partial<UserInstrument | InstrumentProficiencyInput>) {
      super();
      Object.assign(this, init);
  }

  @Column({
      type: 'enum',
      enum: Instrument
  })
  instrument : Instrument

  @Column()
  proficiency : number;

  @JoinColumn()
  @HideField()
  userId : number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, p => p.instruments)
  @HideField()
  user : User;
}
```

Now creating a new user with predefined instruments hasn't been an issue. I can simply insert a new User and it will autofill the `Id` and `UserId` fields for the appropriate tables.

```
  async create(request: RegisterUserInput) : Promise<boolean>{
    const user        = new User();
    user.username     = request.username;
    user.password     = request.password;
    user.phoneNumber  = request.phoneNumber;
    user.email        = request.email;
    user.instruments  = Promise.resolve(request.instruments?.map(p => new UserInstrument(p)));

    const result = await this.usersRepository.save(user);
}
```

#### The issue

Now whenever I do something similar to Update the User/Instrument tables I get a `"ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'userId' cannot be null"` exception

```
  async updateUser(request: UpdateUserInput, id : number): Promise<boolean> {
    var user = new User(classToPlain(request));
    user.id = id;
    user.instruments = Promise.resolve(request.instruments?.map(p => new UserInstrument(p)));

    (await user.instruments)?.forEach(p => p.userId = id);

    await this.usersRepository.save(user);

    return true;
}
```

This code generates the following exception

```
code:'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR'
errno:1048
index:0
message:'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'userId' cannot be null'
name:'QueryFailedError'
parameters:(2) [null, 8]
query:'UPDATE `user_instrument` SET `userId` = ? WHERE `id` = ?'
sql:'UPDATE `user_instrument` SET `userId` = NULL WHERE `id` = 8'
sqlMessage:'Column 'userId' cannot be null'
sqlState:'23000'
stack:'QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'userId' cannot be null
```

Even though when I inspect my user object I can see the `userId` field is set correctly

```
__has_instruments__:true
__instruments__:(1) [UserInstrument]
    0:UserInstrument {created: '2020-11-29 02:46:10', instrument: 'Guitar', proficiency: 5, userId: 30}
length:1
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is there a more *preferred* way to update the users Instrument table, without accessing the Instrument repository directly? I'm not sure why the initial `save` on my create method works, but not on update.

Comment: First of all, there is no SQL code in it, please remove the MySQL tag.....

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?